# How to merge two tables on ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, who have the exact same columns. I want to merge table b into table a and if the dataset has the same ID, I want to use the dataset of table b.

I tried something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM
((SELECT 
    *
FROM
    tableA) UNION  (SELECT 
    *
FROM
    tableB)) AS temp
GROUP BY temp.ID
ORDER BY temp.ID
```

but that gave me a mix of both tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `union all` along with some additional logic:

```
select b.*
from b
union all
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.id = a.id);
```

Comment: exactly :) I was updating my answer to this, but you anticipated me, this is the right answer on this context!